# Set Fancybox iframe size fit to content image

Tags: javascript, fancybox-2

I try many options, but still not working for fit size. 
On the debug mode, when running to "afterLoad" that line, the program is quit immediately.

My Code:

```
$('.fancybox').fancybox({
  fitToView: false,
  autoSize: false,
  type: 'iframe',
  afterLoad: function() {
    $('.fancybox-iframe').load(function() {
      $('.fancybox-inner').height(
        $(this).contents().find('body').height()
      );
      $('.fancybox-inner').width(
        $(this).contents().find('body').width()
      );
    });
  }
});
```

UPDATE:
I found the solutions, not perfect but nearly. Wrong working in Firefox(too small), but right in Chrome:

```
afterLoad: function() {
  this.width = this.content[0].contentDocument.images[0].width;
  this.height = this.content[0].contentDocument.images[0].height;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solutions, not perfect but nearly. Wrong working in Firefox(too small), but right in Chrome:

```
afterLoad: function() {
  this.content[0].contentDocument.images[0].style = ('width: auto; height: auto;');
  this.width = this.content[0].contentDocument.images[0].width;
  this.height = this.content[0].contentDocument.images[0].height;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wants to make it work with firefox as well so use `.naturalWidth` and `.naturalHeight`

```
afterLoad: function() {
    this.content[0].contentDocument.images[0].style = ('width: auto; height: auto;');
    this.width = this.content[0].contentDocument.images[0].naturalWidth;
    this.height = this.content[0].contentDocument.images[0].naturalHeight;
}
```

instead of `.width`and `.height`